# с# visual studio нет доступа из-за уровня защиты и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, ms-word

В Windows Form App следующие ошибки:

InitializeComponent(); - 'Form.InitializeComponent()" недоступен из-за его уровня защиты

string faculty = fac.Text; - Имя fac не существует в текущем контексте

wordDocument.StoryRanges; - "Documents" не содержит определения для "StoryRanges", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "StoryRanges", принимающий "Documents" (заменяла на Text, Content - та же ошибка)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
     partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly string TemplateFileName = @"C:\examticket.docx";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void ExportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string faculty = fac.Text;
            string pulpit = pul.Text;
            string department = dep.Text;
            var direction = dir.Text;
            var course = cou.Text;
            string discipline = dis.Text;
            string year = yea.Text;
            string surname = sur.Text;


            var wordApp = new Word.Application(); //создаем приложение word
            wordApp.Visible = false; //скрываем от пользователя

            try
            {
                var wordDocument = wordApp.Documents.Open(TemplateFileName);
                ReplaceWordStub("{faculty}", faculty, wordDocument);
                ReplaceWordStub("{pulpit}", pulpit, wordDocument);
                ReplaceWordStub("{department}", department, wordDocument);
                ReplaceWordStub("{direction}", direction, wordDocument);
                ReplaceWordStub("{course}", course, wordDocument);
                ReplaceWordStub("{discipline}", discipline, wordDocument);
                ReplaceWordStub("{year}", year, wordDocument);
                ReplaceWordStub("{surname}", surname, wordDocument);
                // Word Export
                wordDocument.SaveAs(@"C:\examticket.docx");
                wordApp.Visible = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Произошла ошибка");
            }
        }

        private void ReplaceWordStub(string v, string faculty, Word.Document wordDocument)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void ReplaceWordStub(string stubToReplace, string text, Word.Documents wordDocument)
        {
            foreach (var item in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Word.WdStoryType)))
            {
                try
                {
                    var range = wordDocument.StoryRanges[(Word.WdStoryType)Enum.Parse(typeof(Word.WdStoryType), item)];
                    range.Find.ClearFormatting();
                    range.Find.Execute(FindText: stubToReplace, ReplaceWith: text);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Делала по https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0me-ntfD8Rk

Comment: `public partial class Form1 : Form` вероятно

Comment: `"Documents" не содержит определения для "StoryRanges"` - смотрите внимательно - вы в метод передаете `Word.Documents` - это коллекция документов, а потом пытаетесь работать как с конкретным документом. Отсюда и ошибка, у коллекции документов нет свойств отдельного документа. Остальные ошибки связаны с тем, как вы создавали форму. Если через визуальный дизанер - то проблема в отсутствии `partial` в объявлении класса `Form1`, а если просто перепечатали код из видео, то у вас просто нет нужных членов класса.

Comment: Через виртуальный дизайнер. Заменила строчку, не помогло